# Hard to find quests in The Rift

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Not being able to finish The Rift quest achievement has been bothering me. Missing it by one quest, I was content chalking this up to being an incorrect count. Well until recently, I came across a group of thugs harassing a noble in Wayrest. After killing the thugs, I was given a quest item that started a chain of quests. I remember this also happening in Bleackrock, in a less similar situation.

Which brings me to my question, are there any less then obvious quests in The Rift. More specifically, what are the locations of quests with no indicators.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ Yah I've seen that before, not sure if there is something in game that tracks my completed quests.

Answer (score 1):

### You can find uncompleted quests per addon

If you're an addon user, [you can use Quest Map](http://www.esoui.com/downloads/info1022-QuestMap.html). This addon shows every location of a non-completed quest on your map.

For me, this is the most easy way to complete the quest achievements.

[image: Look at my quests, my quests are amazing]

The black marks are uncompleted. The white ones are an additional addon setting so that also solved quests are shown on the map (which I won't recommend). So this addon also fits into the ESO standard color scheme of something solved or not.

**Bear in mind that this may reduce immersion, if this is important for you!**

A little flaw: Even following quests are shown as non-completed symbols. This means that if you go to a black exclamation mark and you can't find a quest giver that you first need to solve the required quest in first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of all quests in The Rift [here](http://elderscrollsonline.info/locations/the-rift).

You will also find icons across the map tagging quests you have done, with a tool tip providing information on what you did. Your best bet would be to go through these markers on your map, and tick them off from the official list as you go through.

Failing that, I would recommend tracking down the quests listed on the website that are a little more out of the way then most. It is far less likely your missing quest is from a quest giver that is in a small hut in a more excluded area, for example, then a quest giver in the middle of a main town, surrounded by many other quest givers.